# Why does a DPM protection group configured for Sync work for some databases in simple recovery model but not others?

Tags: sql-server, scdpm

Using System Center Data Protection Manager 10.22.197.0 to back up SQL Server 2022 CU 10 on Windows Server 2022.   DPM agent is also 10.22.197.0 on these SQL servers.  The SQL Server instance was added to DPM protection.  Some of the databases on this SQL Server are in Simple recovery model, others in Full.  The protection group is set to do periodic Synchronization (every 15 minutes) as well as Express Full (1/day).  I realize that Synchronization should not work for databases in Simple recovery model, but in reality, for 3 of the 4 databases in Simple recovery mode, DPM just doesn't try to do Sync jobs for them; while for the 4th database it does try the Sync and fails with the normal error for that scenario ("Execution of SQL command failed for SQL Server 2022 database  on  with reason: BACKUP LOG is terminating abnormally.  The statement BACKUP LOG is not allowed while the recovery model is SIMPLE...").

Any ideas why DPM is treating these databases differently?  The only difference I've identified in the databases themselves is that the "working" ones are at compatibility level 150 and the "failing" one is at compatibility level 160.

thanks

Martin

Comment: if it is a Db specific problem I would suggest that you take a look at [dba.se]

Comment: @djdomi - ok, will try, thanks.

Comment: to do so, just flag your own question for movement and a link will be kept inhere and the transition is the easiest and will have no impact on reputation instead of crossposting

Comment: @djdomi I'll try to remember that for next time...

Answer (score 0):

When a database is configured with the Simple recovery model, the only backup option available is a full backup. This is because the Simple recovery model does not support transaction log backups. Without transaction logs, synchronizing backups incrementally is not possible, as these operations rely on log data to capture changes since the last full or differential backup

Comment: That is understood - I said so in the question.  However, the same protection group has a number of databases configured in Simple recovery model, and for three of them there is no problem - DPM for some reason is not attempting the transaction log backups (apparently).  The question is, why is it treating these different databases differently, on the same SQL Server instance, using the same DPM protection group?